# make element slide by itself after mouse out

Tags: jquery

I have a text options div that's hidden off screen, the user must click or tab to and press enter on the text "tab" in order to show the text options div.

How can I make the div slide back off screen after the user has stopped interacting with it (I guess on mouseOut?) or when a poweruser has tabbed away from it?

[Test page](http://students.cmps.subr.edu/aaron.chauvin/misc/test.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery's animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). There are also a bunch of wrappers, but it sounds as though the animation you are after is a bit more specialised than the stock ones.

To make the animation occur when an event happens, check out [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). There are also some convenience functions for this, but if you want to bind to multiple events at once (e.g. [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) and [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)) then I would advise something along the lines of the following:

```
$(selectorForTheDivInQuestion).bind('mouseleave blur', function(){
    $(this).animate(properies, duration);
});
```

the `properties` could be something along the lines of `{left-margin:-100px;}` or `{left:-100px;}` if the div is relatively, absolutely or fixedly positioned.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I didn't know you could bind to multiple events for the same selector.